# Sequelize subtract updatedAt and createdAt after converted into seconds

Tags: database, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli, sequelize-typescript

Hey I am really new to SEQUELIZE and for this project I am trying to deduct `updatedAt` and `createdAt` value after its converted into seconds.

Updated and createdAt column is on DATETIME format. One of the row consists of createdAt value as `2021-03-03 21:30:58` and updatedAt as `2021-03-03 22:42:05`. Is there a way I can convert that value into seconds first and then deduct it. I tried it below but its not formatting into seconds as well as the `timePlayed` always display the result as 14000.

Can anyone let me know what I am suppose to do on sequelize to format date into seconds and then deduct the value betweeen `createdAt` and `updatedAt`?

```
router.get(
    "/sessions/average_team_time",
    (req, res) => {
      models.Session.findAll({
        createdAt: sequelize.literal('createdAt * 100000'),
        updatedAt: sequelize.literal('updatedAt * 100000')
        'attributes': [
              'id',
              'createdAt',
              'updatedAt',
              [Sequelize.fn('time', Sequelize.col('updatedAt')), 'updatedAtHour'],
              [Sequelize.fn('date_format', Sequelize.col('createdAt'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%S'), 'date_formed'],
              [Sequelize.literal('(updatedAt - createdAt)'), 'timePlayed']
         ]
      })
        .then((sessions) => {
          res.json(sessions);
        })
        .catch((err) => res.json(err));
    }
  );
```

Comment: What DB do you use? Did you search for DB date functions that can get you a difference between two datetime values?

Comment: @Anatoly I am using MySQL database.

Comment: `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function is available at mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.Session.findAll({
    attributes: [
        'id',
        'createdAt',
        'updatedAt',
        [Sequelize.fn('TIMESTAMPDIFF', Sequelize.literal('SECOND'), Sequelize.col("createdAt"), Sequelize.col("updatedAt")), 'timePlayed']

    ]
})
    .then(resp => res.send(resp))
    .catch(error => res.send({ status: false, error: error }))
```

**Sometimes, javascript is more powerful than sequelzie**

```
db.Session.findAll({
    // createdAt: sequelize.literal('createdAt * 100000'),
    // updatedAt: sequelize.literal('updatedAt * 100000'),
    attributes: [
        'id',
        'createdAt',
        'updatedAt',
        [Sequelize.fn('time', Sequelize.col('updatedAt')), 'updatedAtHour'],
        [Sequelize.fn('date_format', Sequelize.col('createdAt'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%S'), 'date_formed'],
        // [Sequelize.literal('(updatedAt - createdAt)'), 'timePlayed']
    ]
})
    .then((sessions) => {
        sessions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sessions))
        sessions = sessions || []
        sessions = sessions.map(item => {
            item.timePlayed = new Date(item.updatedAt).getTime() - new Date(item.createdAt).getTime()
            return item;
        })
        res.json(sessions);
    })
    .catch((err) => res.json(err));
```

**Or, we can use DataTypes.VIRTUAL**

model: define

```
Session.init({
    timePlayed: {
        type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
        get() {
            return new Date(this.updatedAt).getTime() - new Date(this.createdAt).getTime()
        }
    }
})

...

db.Session.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt', 'timePlayed']
})
    .then(resp => res.send(resp))
    .catch(error => res.send({ status: false, error: error }))
```